# Closing Modal-dialog box after clicking "OK" in Vue.Js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, modal-dialog

Overview: I am trying to close the modal dialog box after I click OK, in Vue.js. Currently, it does not close upon clicking OK, but closes upon clicking "Cancel", clicking outside the box and pressing ESC key.
the method being called after clicking the button is also given at end. Thanks!

```
  <b-button-group class="mx-2" size="lg">
      <b-button
            @click="$bvModal.show('modal-1')"
            variant="light" class="border border-muted">
        <strong class="text-muted">Löschen  &raquo;</strong></b-button>
      <b-modal id="modal-1" title="Bitte bestätigen">
        <p class="my-4">Are you sure, you want to delete it?</p>
        <template v-slot:modal-footer="{ ok, cancel,}">
          
      <!-- Emulate built in modal footer ok and cancel button actions -->
      <b-button size="sm" variant="success" @click="okButtonClicked()" > OK </b-button>
      <b-button size="sm" variant="danger" @click="cancel()"> Cancel </b-button>
    </template>
      </b-modal>
    </b-button-group>
```

methods: {

```
    okButtonClicked: async function() { 
      let td_id =this.form.TransportDemandsId;
      console.log(this.form.TransportDemandsId);
      let url = "https://localhost:44370/api/transportdemand/abort/" + td_id;
      const res = await axios.delete(url);      
      let data = res.data;
      
      if (data === true) {
        alert("Response: OK. Transport Demand is Deleted: " );
      } else {
        alert("Response: Transport Demand not found");
      };
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your method okButtonClicked the closing function is missing. Add `this.$bvModal.hide('modal-1');` in method `okButtonClicked` in line you want to close the modal. Probably at the end of the function.